# Copying files from /usr/local/lib into /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages in Raspbian-stretch

Tags: linux, file-copying, raspbian-stretch

I have some files in /usr/local/lib and I need to copy them in this folder /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages. These files are not copied in this folder correctly due to permission issues.

I tried this command but didnt work either.

```
 sudo cp libopencv_aruco.so.3.3  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Kindly guide how can I copy these files into mentioned folder.

Comment: `sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libopencv_aruco.so.3.3  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. Btw., libopencv_aruco.so.3.3 may have symlinks to it in that directory, that would probably also need to be copied. Other than that, I hope you know what you're doing.

Comment: You can find out if /usr/local/lib/libopencv_aruco.so.3.3 has any symlinks to it by doing `find -L / -samefile /usr/local/lib/libopencv_aruco.so.3.3`.  Those would need to be copied also. After having copied them, run `sudo ldconfig`.

Comment: Yes I know others need to be copied also. But How do I change the administration previleges of all the files present in /usr/local folder. Right now these files are not being able to be copied.

Comment: Run `sudo su` to give you root privileges, and perform the changes. Then, when done, type `exit` (or type ^D, i.e. control-D), and you're back from your root privileges.

Comment: sudo su
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# cp libopencv_aruco.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
cp: cannot stat 'libopencv_aruco.so': No such file or directory                                                                         Tried by doing this still didnt work. Kindly correct me if I am wrong in my implementation of what you said.

Comment: Or alternatively: `cd /usr/local/lib` and then `cp libopencv_aruco.so.3.3 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Comment: Thanks it works. But there are over 80 such files which need  to be copied. Is there any other way of copying them instead of doing this one by one, please suggest.

Comment: That depends. If the whole directory with > 80 files needs to be copied, you can of course do that. Or sometimes it's easier to copy all files, and afterwards remove the excess ones.

Comment: Sometimes, what I do is create an ad-hoc script, starting with the output from `/bin/ls -1 | while IFS= read -r line; do printf "cp -axvp 'SRC/%s' 'DEST/%s'\n" "$line" "$line"; done` (where SRC and DEST are source and destination directories). I then VERY CAREFULLY inspect and edit that script, weeding out files that I do not want copied, check and double check, and then perform the copy by doing `bash script`.